# Primitives.StringValues - how to deserialize value that looks like an array into an array

Tags: c#, deserialization, query-string, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an REST api with MVC6 project with the dotnet core framework.
I am trying to deserialize some query parameters into an array
I get the following GET request:

```
http://localhost:53384/api/things?sortModel=%7B%22colId%22:%22arrivalDate%22,%22sort%22:%22asc%22%7D&sortModel=%7B%22colId%22:%22arrivalPortCode%22,%22sort%22:%22desc%22%7D
```

the sort model is an array that contains key (the column Id) value ("asc" or "desc") pairs and I am trying to have this query parameter converted to a `List<SortModel>` being:

```
public class SortModel
{
    public string ColId { get; set; }
    public string Sort { get; set; }
}
```

At the controller, I can extract the query param with:

```
IReadableStringCollection paramsCollection = Request.Query;
```

But then I need this method to work:

```
IEnumerable<SortModel> sortModel = GetSortModel(paramsCollection["sortModel");

private IEnumerable<SortModel> GetSortModel(string sortModel)
{
    // the sortModel string looks like this: "{\"colId\":\"arrivalDate\",\"sort\":\"asc\"},{\"colId\":\"arrivalPortCode\",\"sort\":\"desc\"}"
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SortModel>>(sortModel); //this throws an exception but the exception itself is null
    return deserialized;
}
```

Notice that the sortModel string is not wrapped with `[]` nor with `{}` although the paramsCollection value for that key seems to be a `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues` with the following value:
`{{"colId":"arrivalDate","sort":"asc"},{"colId":"arrivalPortCode","sort":"desc"}}`

Not sure why the value is wrapped with `{}` instead with `[]` but that's how it is retrieved in the request.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by manually transforming the string into a json array, although that does not seem a "natural" way of dealing with this so I'm keen to hear about better built-in options for deserializing an array query parameter.

Here is how I resolved it:

```
private IEnumerable<SortModel> GetSortModel(string sortModel)
{
     if (sortModel == null)
     {
         return Enumerable.Empty<SortModel>();
     }
     string array = $"[{sortModel}]"; 
     var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SortModel>>(array);
     return deserialized;
 }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a more "natural" way of dealing with this?  It looks like `Primitives.StringValues.ToArray()` might be what you were looking for.